# webdriver - Utility / helper method - wait until class name contains specific style attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a webapp that will contain a class of "Loading" which, when fully loaded on the page, will contain a width property of 100% else it will contain nothing.  I'm trying to perform a check on this style attribute but I keep getting a timeout.  here is what I'm doing:

I'm calling code from within a helper / utility class as follows as this is something I will be using frequently in multiple classes:

```
Utility.WaitForStyle("Loading", Utility.driver);
```

In my helper / utility class I have the following code:

```
public static void WaitForStyle(string Class, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    IWebElement element = d.FindElement(By.ClassName(Class));
                    String elementresults = element.GetAttribute("style");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(elementresults);


                    return false;
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

Note, The code above is currently just looking to check that it can get a handle on the class's style attribute but it's not getting to that point.  I know the problem lies within the utility method as I can use the following code in individual classes:

```
IWebElement element = Utility.driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Loading"));
String elementresults = element.GetAttribute("style");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(elementresults);
```

This will printout "width: 100%" as expected so I know that this block of code is actually working ok.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something silly in my utility method?

Comment: Are your `return`'s the wrong way round?

Comment: What Arran said. Plus your prose description of what you are trying to do does not correspond to your code, even if we switch the `return` statements around. Your description implies that the element of class `Loading` always present but may or may not have a `style` that has `width: 100%`. Your code tests for the presence of the element.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my code to wait for an element attribute to have a specific value. It assumes the element passed to it has been verified to exist:

```
public bool WaitForAttribute(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, string attributeName, string attributeValue, int timeOut = 5)
{
    // Build a function with a signature compatible with the WebDriverWait.Until method
    Func<IWebDriver, bool> testCondition = (x) => element.GetAttribute(attributeName).Equals(attributeValue);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));

    // Wait until either the test condition is true or timeout
    try { wait.Until(testCondition); }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException e) { }

    // Return a value to indicate if our wait was successful
    return testCondition.Invoke(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, since more than 4 months.

```
 public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumInfo.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    public static void WaitUntilAttributeValueEquals(this IWebElement webElement, String attributeName, String attributeValue)
        {            
                wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
                {
                    if (webElement.GetAttribute(attributeName) == attributeValue)
                    {
                        return webElement;
                    }
                    return null;
                });
        }
```